# AsyncDisplayKit Error (Using ASDK as static Library)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I have added the ASDK as a static library to my project.  I want to test it out so I add a ASTextnode.  I then get the following errors and I do not know why. Any help would be appreciated

```
Ld /Users/ap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ASGallery-fzvzhorqnjotpzchjozqlryhsleh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ASGallery.app/ASGallery normal x86_64 cd "/Users/ap/Documents/Xcode Projects/_Apps/ASGallery" export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0 export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk
-L/Users/ap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ASGallery-fzvzhorqnjotpzchjozqlryhsleh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/ap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ASGallery-fzvzhorqnjotpzchjozqlryhsleh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-filelist /Users/ap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ASGallery-fzvzhorqnjotpzchjozqlryhsleh/Build/Intermediates/ASGallery.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ASGallery.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ASGallery.LinkFileList
-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lc++ -ObjC -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
-Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/ap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ASGallery-fzvzhorqnjotpzchjozqlryhsleh/Build/Intermediates/ASGallery.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ASGallery.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ASGallery.swiftmodule /Users/ap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ASGallery-fzvzhorqnjotpzchjozqlryhsleh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAsyncDisplayKit.a
-framework Photos -framework AssetsLibrary -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ASGallery-fzvzhorqnjotpzchjozqlryhsleh/Build/Intermediates/ASGallery.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ASGallery.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ASGallery_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/ap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ASGallery-fzvzhorqnjotpzchjozqlryhsleh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ASGallery.app/ASGallery


Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_llvm_gcda_emit_arcs", referenced from: ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASHierarchyChangeSet.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASDisplayView.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASAsciiArtBoxCreator.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBackgroundLayoutSpec.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASFlowLayoutController.o)
___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBasicImageDownloader.o) ... "_llvm_gcda_emit_function", referenced from: ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASHierarchyChangeSet.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASDisplayView.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASAsciiArtBoxCreator.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBackgroundLayoutSpec.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASFlowLayoutController.o)
___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBasicImageDownloader.o) ... "_llvm_gcda_end_file", referenced from: ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASHierarchyChangeSet.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASDisplayView.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASAsciiArtBoxCreator.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBackgroundLayoutSpec.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASFlowLayoutController.o)
___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBasicImageDownloader.o) ... "_llvm_gcda_start_file", referenced from: ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASHierarchyChangeSet.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASDisplayView.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASAsciiArtBoxCreator.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBackgroundLayoutSpec.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASFlowLayoutController.o)
___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBasicImageDownloader.o) ... "_llvm_gcda_summary_info", referenced from: ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASHierarchyChangeSet.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASDisplayView.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASAsciiArtBoxCreator.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBackgroundLayoutSpec.o) ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASFlowLayoutController.o)
___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(ASBasicImageDownloader.o) ... "_llvm_gcov_init", referenced from: ___llvm_gcov_init in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ___llvm_gcov_init64 in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o)
___llvm_gcov_init65 in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ___llvm_gcov_init66 in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o)
___llvm_gcov_init67 in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ___llvm_gcov_init68 in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o)
___llvm_gcov_init69 in libAsyncDisplayKit.a(_ASAsyncTransactionGroup.o) ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some architecture for iPhone simulator i386 and x86_64.
And there are `armv7 arm64` for iPhone OS.

Your project was build with architecture x86_64.
But the static library don't have this .

> See ? ==> `But  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`

---

You can use `lipo` to create or operate on universal (multi-architec-
       ture)) files.

```
lipo $BUILDPATH/$FRAMEWORK.i386.dylib $BUILDPATH/$FRAMEWORK.x86_64.dylib $BUILDPATH/$FRAMEWORK.armv7.dylib $BUILDPATH/$FRAMEWORK.arm64.dylib -create -output $BUILDPATH/$FRAMEWORK
```